# Strange SQL wasting my resources

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, odbc

I'm facing an issue on my 11.2.0.3 database, with a strange query that is responsible for 47.42% of total DB activity.

The app was developed with Flex and the front end is an Apache Tomcat 6.0.35 with Java version 1.6.0_27.

I have searched on several sites and found other people with same issue, even on this site ( [Mysterious SQL blocking my stored procedure from executing on ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894896/mysterious-sql-blocking-my-stored-procedure-from-executing-on-oracle) ), but no solution found so far :-(

The query is:

```
     SELECT package_name AS procedure_cat,
            owner AS procedure_schem,
            object_name AS procedure_name,
            argument_name AS column_name,
            DECODE(position,
                     0, 5,
                        DECODE(in_out,
                                 'IN',     1,
                                 'OUT',    4,
                                 'IN/OUT', 2,
                                           0)) AS column_type,
            DECODE (data_type,
                      'CHAR', 1,
                      'VARCHAR2', 12,
                      'NUMBER', 3,
                      'LONG', -1,
                      'DATE', 91,
                      'RAW', -3,
                      'LONG RAW', -4,
                      'TIMESTAMP', 93,
                      'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE', -101,
                      'TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE', -102,
                      'INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH', -103,
                      'INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND', -104,
                      'BINARY_FLOAT', 100,
                      'BINARY_DOUBLE', 101,
                                       1111) AS data_type,
            DECODE(data_type,
                     'OBJECT', type_owner || '.' || type_name,
                               data_type) AS type_name,
            DECODE (data_precision,
                      NULL, data_length,
                            data_precision) AS precision,
            data_length AS length,
            data_scale AS scale,
            10 AS radix,
            1 AS nullable,
            NULL AS remarks,
            sequence,
            overload,
            default_value
  FROM all_arguments
  WHERE owner LIKE :1 ESCAPE '/'
        AND object_name LIKE :2 ESCAPE '/'
        AND package_name IS NULL
        AND (argument_name LIKE :5 ESCAPE '/'
             OR (argument_name IS NULL
                 AND data_type IS NOT NULL))
  ORDER BY procedure_schem, procedure_name, overload, sequence
```

I'm wondering if someone has found the solution?

Comment: Has your DBA run statistics on the system tables? If not, that could be the cause of slow performance on this query.

Comment: who/what is running this? (known user, SYS?) and from what program?  get session info from DBAs first

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
The statistics are in place. The query is being executed for several users, but it's not in our app, this is something from the java itself. I've found this query in the OracleDatabaseMetaData.java component. What I need to find is why and how to avoid the execution, or at least, reduce the number of executions. I've found as far as 100mil executions/hour :-(
It seems to be executed every time the app calls an SP

Comment: By the way, I am the DBA. I find that query in every addm report. I've searched in the oracle support site and found nothing. I've found similar questions in several forums, even this and oracle forum, but no solution or clear answers found :-(

Comment: check the app code where it uses oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData Is it calling getProcedureColumns (or getProcedures) by any chance? (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns_java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String_ )

Comment: tbone, I've posted your question to our development team. I will back to you as soon as I get an answer from them, thanks.

Comment: They have found some useless calls to "call.getProcedureName()". A new app version is being cooked. Hopefully, it will solve the issue, I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look in the results cache feature.

Comment: Hi Steve, following your advice I've read about the cache result. It looks like a powerfull tool, thanks. Sadly, it can't be applied to my issue, as the variables in my query are bind and you need real values to cache the result :-(

Comment: The I+D department is following the case. They have found a relationship with the spring component. Once the issue be resolved, I will share an update. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Does your code, perchance, use Spring's SimpleJdbcCall class?  This class attempts to get information about the stored procedure and caches the results.  So make sure you instantiate the SimpleJdbcCall class once, and reuse it for each invocation of the stored procedure.

Alternately, you can call withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess() when constructing the SimpleJdbcCall object.

Comment: can you give any evidence that SimpleJdbcCall will cache metadata query result . i just want to make sure

Comment: For following  reason in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75588589/spring-simplejdbccall-stored-procedure-parameters-getting-exchanged i made SimpleJdbc method local now metadata query is happening for each storedproc  call