# oracle internal queries consuming more IO and CPU

Tags: spring, oracle, performance, query-optimization, jdbctemplate

We are using Orace 11g. In our production environment we are facing db slowness.When we check the AWR report we find that below query is consuming 
more IO and CPU times. But we are not using this query in our application.Below is that query

```
SELECT arg.package_name AS procedure_cat, arg.owner AS procedure_schem, arg.object_name AS procedure_name, arg.argument_name AS column_name,
DECODE(arg.position, :"SYS_B_000", :"SYS_B_001", DECODE(arg.in_out, :"SYS_B_002", :"SYS_B_003", :"SYS_B_004", :"SYS_B_005", :"SYS_B_006", :"SYS_B_007", :"SYS_B_008")) AS column_type, 
DECODE( (SELECT a.typecode FROM ALL_TYPES A WHERE a.type_name = arg.data_type), :"SYS_B_009", :"SYS_B_010", :"SYS_B_011", :"SYS_B_012", 
DECODE(substr(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_013", :"SYS_B_014"), :"SYS_B_015", DECODE(substr(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_016", :"SYS_B_017"), :"SYS_B_018",
DECODE(substr(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_019", :"SYS_B_020"), :"SYS_B_021", -:"SYS_B_022", :"SYS_B_023", -:"SYS_B_024", :"SYS_B_025"),
DECODE(substr(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_026", :"SYS_B_027"), :"SYS_B_028", -:"SYS_B_029", :"SYS_B_030", -:"SYS_B_031", :"SYS_B_032")), :"SYS_B_033", 
DECODE(substr(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_034", :"SYS_B_035"), :"SYS_B_036", -:"SYS_B_037", :"SYS_B_038", -:"SYS_B_039"),
DECODE(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_040", :"SYS_B_041", :"SYS_B_042", :"SYS_B_043", :"SYS_B_044", -:"SYS_B_045", :"SYS_B_046", :"SYS_B_047", 
:"SYS _B_048", :"SYS_B_049", :"SYS_B_050", :"SYS_B_051", :"SYS_B_052", :"SYS_B_053", :"SYS_B_054", :"SYS_B_055", :"SYS_B_056", :"SYS_B_057",
:"SYS_B_058", -:"SYS_B_059", :"SYS_B_060", -:"SYS_B_061", :"SYS_B_062", -:"SYS_B_063", :"SYS_B_064", :"SYS_B_065", :"SYS_B_066", :"SYS_B_067", 
:"SYS_B_068", -:"SYS_B_069", :"SYS_B_070", -:"SYS_B_071", :"SYS_B_072", :"SYS_B_073", :"SYS_B_074", :"SYS_B_075", :"SYS_B_076", -:"SYS_B_077",
:"SYS_B_078", :"SYS_B_079", :"SYS_B_080", -:"SYS_B_081", :"SYS_B_082", :"SY S_B_083", :"SYS_B_084", -:"SYS_B_085", :"SYS_B_086", :"SYS_B_087",
:"SYS_B_088", :"SYS_B_089", :"SYS_B_090", :"SYS_B_091", :"SYS_B_092"))) AS data_type,
DECODE(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_093", arg.type_owner || :"SYS_B_094" || arg.type_name, arg.data_type) AS type_name,
DECODE (arg.data_precision, NULL, arg.data_length, arg.data_precision) AS precision, arg.data_length AS length,
arg.data_scale AS scale, :"SYS_B_095" AS radix, :"SYS_B_096" AS nullable, NULL AS remarks, arg.default_value AS column_def, NULL as sql_data_type, NULL AS sql_datetime_sub, 
DECODE(arg.data_type, :"SYS_B_097", :"SYS_B_098", : "SYS_B_099", :"SYS_B_100", :"SYS_B_101", :"SYS_B_102", :"SYS_B_103", :"SYS_B_104", :"SYS_B_105", :"SYS_B_106", NULL) AS
char_octet_length, (arg.sequence - :"SYS_B_107") AS ordinal_position, :"SYS_B_108" AS is_nullable, NULL AS specific_name, arg.sequence, arg.overload, arg.default_value 
FROM all_arguments arg
     , all_procedures proc 
WHERE arg.owner LIKE :1 ESCAPE :"SYS_B_109" 
AND arg.object_name LIKE :2 ESCAPE :"SYS_B_110" 
AND arg.data_level = :"SYS_B_111" 
AND arg.owner = proc.owner AND arg.object_id = proc.object_id AND arg.subprogram_id = proc.subprogram_id AND arg.package_name IS NULL 
AND (arg.argument_name LIKE :5 ESCAPE :"SYS_B_112" OR (arg.argument_name IS NULL AN D arg.data_type IS NOT NULL)) 
ORDER BY procedure_schem, procedure_name, overload, sequence
```

We are using `JDBCTemplate` for connecting the oracle database.

I want the solutions like

1. Either I have to stop the execution of this query.
2. I have to reduce the IO and CPU usage of this query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Looks like this (but made worse by cursor_sharing = force): https://stackoverflow.com/q/11934749/230471

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, Thanks I am also using simple jdbc call I will implement the solution shared in the link and let you know the results.

Comment: @APC Thanks for the explanation. Hope it only generates for procedure call right?